# How to share events code in a microservice architecture

Tags: events, design-patterns, architecture, domain-driven-design, microservices

I'm working on a "microservice-like" architecture. Each microservice can fire some events to RabbitMQ. The events are identified by an event code. At the moment, the code of the event triggered is an hard coded const string declared inside the microservice that fire the event.
My problem is that each microservice that want to subscribe to this event must duplicate this event code string. This is error prone especially when an event code is renamed because all microservices that subscribed to this event code need to be changed accordingly... which is very bad.

I see the possible alternatives:

- Declare the event code only in the microservice that fire the event. Let the consumers microservices directly access to the code declared in the microservice that fire the event. In this case, the event is declared once but it creates a source code dependency between microservices... which is bad.
- Create a source file (outside all microservices) that contains all the events code of all the application. This source file is shared by all microservices. In this case, each event is declared once but it creates a global dependency for all microservices which is against the single responsability principle... which is bad.

How do you tackle this problem ?

Comment: How do microservices communicate on you architecture? Can't you use some message bus that shares information? Each microservice could communicate to a queue for the event code fired, with timestamp or other unique and relevant information, thus removing source code dependencies.

Comment: Yes this is very precisely my problem. I use rabbitMQ. Both the publisher and the consumer microservice need to know event code (and payload) in order to publish for the first one and to decode for the second one.

Comment: I think if you want to have a truly effective microservice architecture you should have a shared nothing architecture means whatever you have now is the best way to handle it.  I don't see the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: "Create a source file (outside all microservices) that contains all the events code of all the application" --
This. The loose coupling of microservices is often stressed, so it's natural to feel apprehensive about an apparent contradiction like this. But of course microservices must communicate to function as a system. Where events define the interface between them, it's fine to share these common interface definitions in a common source file or library. Note each microservice is not obliged to use the same version of this events file/library, so it doesn't impact evolution of events.

Answer (score 2):

> At the moment, the code of the event triggered is an hard coded const string declared inside the microservice that fire the event. My problem is that each microservice that want to subscribe to this event must duplicate this event code string. This is error prone especially when an event code is renamed because all microservices that subscribed to this event code need to be changed accordingly... which is very bad.

Events are *messages*.  All of the constraints that we use to manage the evolution of messages applies to events as well.

In a microservices architecture, we expect to be able to deploy instances of the services independently of one another.  Requiring that all of the services shut down together to coordinate a change in message schema kind of misses the point.  That in turn implies that we need to design reasonable behaviors for the cases where the producer and consumer don't have matching understandings of the message.

In practice, this means something like

- We never introduce a new required field, only optional fields (with documented default values).
- Unrecognized fields are ignored (but forwarded)
- Consumers of optional fields know to use default value to use when an expected field is missing.
- When these constraints cannot be satisfied, then you are introducing a *new* message.

If you have the message contracts in place, then you aren't restricting yourself to microservice implementations that share the same runtime platform (because two different implementations of the same contract are equivalent).

Recommend reading:

- [ZeroMQ RFC 42/C4](https://rfc.zeromq.org/spec:42/C4#26-evolution-of-public-contract), specifically section 2.6 which describes the evolution of public contracts
- [Versioning in an Event Sourced System](https://leanpub.com/esversioning), speficically "Basic Type Based Versioning"